# Set hidden field value from C# backend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to set a hidden field value from my C# backend.

#### My JS code :

```
function GetSignedMessage() {
    try {
        document.getElementById("hdnbyteToRecieve1").value = "PPPP";
        document.getElementById("<%=hdnbyteToRecieve.ClientID %>").value = "PPPP";
        //document.SignedAppletDemo_View.getpdf();
    } catch (err) {
       alert(err.message);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am calling this js function from backend code.

#### My C# code :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "disp_confirm", "GetSignedMessage();", true);
var aa = hdnbyteToRecieve1.Value;
```

Somehow, the value of hidden field `hdnbyteToRecieve1` and `hdnbyteToRecieve` is coming empty.

Comment: Obviously it will be _empty_ because the _GetSignedMessage_ function is on the client side and when you call this from server it will be executed only after the server code execution is completed thus you are getting the value as empty. What you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Adil.. this script is written on  some `button` click

Comment: @RahulSingh  .Is there a way to execute this script code parallely with server code ? Any suggestions?

Comment: @RahulSingh. I am trying to set hidden field value as a result from an `java applet`.

Comment: That's why I asked what you are doing and when? I mean a button click event or something? Better to set it during client side interaction itself.

Comment: try using DOM in browser.